# How to create loading screen in my case

Tags: javascript, php, loading

My app is doing large amount of database queries and it holds the loading page blank white while doing it. I was wondering if there is anyway I can show the loading icon during the query.

```
<?php
    //large queries
    //if all queries pass
    //do the redirect
    header('Location: index.html');
    //else show login screen.
?>

<html>
    //show login screen….
</html>
```

My question is how to show the loading icon when php query database

Thanks.

Comment: What @PatrickQ said, or you can create a page that only shows the loading screen, then redirect from it to the long-loading page.

Comment: use `ob_flush` to send some content while running the query

Comment: @PatrickQ How can we detect the php loading with ajax?

Comment: When your (login?) page loads, display your loading icon, and then fire an ajax request that will do your "large queries". You can either do this before any other content loads, or you could load your regular login content and simply put the loading icon over it. If the queries pass, redirect. If not, hide the loading icon and display your login content (if you're not already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. redirect user to a loading page 2. make an ajax request to the actual content script (does the heavy lifting) 3. when content is ready replace part of the loading page with actual content

Example of a loading page: (index.php returns content of body -element for the page)

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("index.php", function(data) {
    $("body").html(data);
    console.log("page was loaded");
  });
});
</script>
<html>
  <body>
    page is loading // <- shown while loading the page
  </body>
</html>
```

note: example above expects that jquery is included